# Django + Guncorn + nginx: 111: Connection refused; bad gateway 502

Tags: django

For some reason, it does not work. Do you see any issues in this code? Thank you for your review in advance!

Error.log:

```
2019/11/10 18:02:02 [error] 8761#8761: *1 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: demid.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

Terminal:

```
demid@demid-Aspire-7736:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
demid@demid-Aspire-7736:~$ systemctl daemon-reload
demid@demid-Aspire-7736:~$ systemctl restart gunicorn.socket gunicorn.service nginx.service; systemctl status gunicorn.socket gunicorn.service nginx.service
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: No such file or directory
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-11-10 17:59:39 EET; 288ms ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

lapkr. 10 17:59:39 demid-Aspire-7736 systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.

● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-11-10 17:59:39 EET; 213ms ago
 Main PID: 8756 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4669)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           └─8756 /home/demid/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/python3 /home/demid/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn

lapkr. 10 17:59:39 demid-Aspire-7736 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.

● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-11-10 17:59:39 EET; 70ms ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
Process: 8757 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, 
  Process: 8759 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8758 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8760 (nginx)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4669)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─8760 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─8761 nginx: worker process
           └─8762 nginx: worker process

lapkr. 10 17:59:39 demid-Aspire-7736 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
lapkr. 10 17:59:39 demid-Aspire-7736 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/demid.com.conf

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    demid.com;
    location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}
    location /static/ {
root /demid/myprojectdir;
    }

    location / {
include proxy_params;
#proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
#    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    #proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/myproject/myproject.sock;
proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
}
}
```

/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After = network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/demid/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/demid/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
--access-logfile - \
--workers 3 \
--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 50000;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
    keepalive_requests 256;
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/xml+rss image/png image/gif image/jpeg image/jpg;

    open_file_cache max=50000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;

    client_max_body_size 512m;

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: Is the file `/run/gunicorn.sock` readable and writable for users running `nginx`, `gunicorn` and `django`? Is the `gunicorn` service running and listening on the socket? Do you see anything in the `gunicorn` logs?

Comment: Hi Paolo,
1. what users exactly you mean? I wrote "root" with hope that it has all rights - you can check this above.
2. Is the gunicorn service running and listening on the socket? systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket. (more details you can find above in Terminal section)
3. Do you see anything in the gunicorn logs? 2019/11/10 18:02:02 [error] 8761#8761: *1 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: demid.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I am a beginner, if I answered not what you expected, please write me what to do and I will do it

Comment: Gunicorn user seems ok, but I can't find [user directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#user) for nginx. It should be in `http` section. Please run `ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock`, what are the permissions and owner? For now you can try `chmod 777 /run/gunicorn.sock`, restart all services and see if there's any change. The 777 permissions are never recommended, if this works, set the permissions and owner properly. (I am also no expert, just throwing questions and ideas.)

Comment: Paolo, thank you a lot for your help!

I checked ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock - owner is "root". only root has permissions for this file (i checked this manually). Also, I can't change these permissions because, it is written,I am not the owner for this file. Output:
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 lapkr 10 20:34 /run/gunicorn.sock

chmod didn't help to change permissions. 
chmod: changing permissions of '/run/gunicorn.sock': Operation not permitted

Comment: That still doesn't fit, `rw-rw-rw-` means "read and write permissions for everyone" (and the `s` at the beginning probably denotes a socket). You cannot change permissions because you are not the owner, but that's not the reason why nginx cannot connect to gunicorn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100880/discussion-between-paolo-and-demid-cerkov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize - `nginx` was returning `111: Connection refused` after trying to connect to `gunicorn` through a UNIX socket located at `/run/gunicorn.sock`.

At first we made sure this wasn't a permission issue:

```
# ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 lapkr 10 20:34 /run/gunicorn.sock
```

The `rw-rw-rw-` means that every user can read and write into the file.

(Side note - these permissions are too broad, better practice might be to make sure that `nginx` workers are run by the same user as `gunicorn.service` and grant RW permissions only to this user, but this answer is focused mainly on making the connection work, and this really isn't my domain anyway.)

The next action was to list processes listening on the socket:

```
# netstat --protocol=unix -nlp | grep 'gunicorn'
```

(Instead of `gunicorn` you can also grep full socket path, but here it was enough).

Output was empty, `gunicorn` wasn't listening.

After looking at gunicorn service logs:

```
# systemctl status gunicorn.service
# journalctl -u gunicorn.service
```

we found that the socket binding failed with message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.wsgi'
```

This was caused by using wrong path to Python application for socket binding in `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`.

The file contains two params that affect this - `WorkingDirectory` and `ExecStart`.

The `WorkingDirectory` must point to a directory that contains the main `gunicorn` config file - `settings.py`.

The `ExecStart` must contain the main command to run the `gunicorn` virtualenv binary. You need to run it with the option `--bind /run/gunicorn.sock myproject.wsgi:application`, where `/run/gunicorn.sock` is socket filepath and `myproject.wsgi:application` is relative path to Python module entrypoint (dirs are separated by dots, extension `.py` is ommitted, module name is followed by colon and a callable `application` variable).

Comment: Thank you Paolo!

Comment: I recorded the install here: https://youtu.be/AzheRKRS6eo
It will become available in a minute.